# Deprecated with(Context) method

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android.

I'm trying to select the file and read it in android java. To choose a file, I'm using https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6982 file chooser library.

But it's showing that `.with(this)` is deprecated. What I can replace it with to get rid of the warning?

Screenshot of warning: https://imghostr.com/xapXZzqE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally just scroll down that page a bit and take a look at this:

> **New calling chain**
>
> 1.1.7+, new constructor ChooserDialog(context) can simplify the chain invoking, such as:

```
    new ChooserDialog(this)
        .withFilter(true, false)
        .withStartFile(startingDir)
        ...
```

Comment: Literally, I want to kick myself. Thanks @Vucko

Comment: No worries man, happens to everyone. Btw try holding `CTRL` (or `CMD` on mac) and clicking on `with` method trying to see if it'll take you to the implementation of it, sometimes the 3rd party libs have nice comments and all, so you can literally figure it out alone even if there's no good docs for them. Or `CTRL` click on the constructor itself. Or hit `CTRL+P` while your cursor is in brackets of the constructor to see possible parameters for it.